# Finding if a point is on a rectangle

Tags: prolog, shapes

Hi I am trying to figure out if a point is on a rectangle using Prolog. Where (ULX,ULY) is the upper left point of the rectangle and (LRX,LRY) is lower right point of the rectangle and (X,Y) is the point I am using to check if it is on the shape:

[image]

I tried this but I kept getting the error(=:=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated)

```
on(point2d(X,Y), rectangle(point2d(ULX, ULY), point2d(LRX, LRY))):-

URX is LRX,
URY is ULY,

LLX is ULX,
LLY is LRY,

%Checks if point is in area 1
(Y =:= ULY,
  X > ULX,
  X < URX)
;

 %OR Checks if point is in area 2
 (X =:= URX,
  Y < URY,
  Y > LRY)
;

 %OR Checks if point is in area 4
 (X =:= ULX,
  Y < ULY,
  Y > LLY)
;

 %OR Checks if point is in area 3
 (Y =:= LLY,
  X > LLX,
  X < LRX)
;


  (X =:= ULX,
  Y =:= ULY)
;

 (X =:= URX,
  Y =:= URY)
;

 (X =:= LLX,
  Y =:= LLY)
;

 X =:= LRX,
  Y =:= LRY.
```

So I tired to separate them into cases. But if the point is on the rectangle I get a true value followed by a false. If it's false I just get one false value. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
 %Checks if point is in area 1
on(point2d(X,Y), rectangle(point2d(ULX, ULY), point2d(LRX, _))):-
URX is LRX,
%URY is ULY,

%LLX is ULX,
%LLY is LRY,

  Y =:= ULY,
  X > ULX,
  X < URX.

 %OR Checks if point is in area 2
on(point2d(X,Y), rectangle(point2d(_, ULY), point2d(LRX, LRY))):-
URX is LRX,
URY is ULY,

%LLX is ULX,
%LLY is LRY,

X =:= URX,
  Y < URY,
  Y > LRY.

 %OR Checks if point is in area 4
on(point2d(X,Y), rectangle(point2d(ULX, ULY), point2d(_, LRY))):-
%URX is LRX,
%URY is ULY,

%LLX is ULX,
LLY is LRY,

 X =:= ULX,
  Y < ULY,
  Y > LLY.

 %OR Checks if point is in area 3
on(point2d(X,Y), rectangle(point2d(ULX, _), point2d(LRX, LRY))):-
%URX is LRX,
%URY is ULY,

LLX is ULX,
LLY is LRY,

 Y =:= LLY,
  X > LLX,
  X < LRX.
on(point2d(X,Y), rectangle(point2d(ULX, ULY), point2d(_, _))):-
% URX is LRX,
%URY is ULY,

 %LLX is ULX,
 %LLY is LRY,

 X =:= ULX,
  Y =:= ULY.

on(point2d(X,Y), rectangle(point2d(_, ULY), point2d(LRX, _))):-
URX is LRX,
URY is ULY,

%LLX is ULX,
%LLY is LRY,

X =:= URX,
  Y =:= URY.

on(point2d(X,Y), rectangle(point2d(ULX, _), point2d(_, LRY))):-
%URX is LRX,
%URY is ULY,

LLX is ULX,
LLY is LRY,

X =:= LLX,
  Y =:= LLY.

on(point2d(X,Y), rectangle(point2d(_, _), point2d(LRX, LRY))):-
% URX is LRX,
% URY is ULY,

% LLX is ULX,
%LLY is LRY,

X =:= LRX,
Y =:= LRY.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rectangles are not rotated arbitrarily and your points are all integral, you're making life a little harder on yourself by having variables for all the dimensions. I would start with this  for the first side:

```
on(point2d(X,Y), rectangle(point2d(ULX,Y), point2d(LRX, LRY))) :-
  between(ULX, LRX, X).
```

I've equated the Y on the point to the Y on the upper right point to sort of "lock" onto that side; then I'm just using between for the X value of the point. This is only slightly more work without integers and `between/3`. The other three clauses will look the same, just locking onto each of the other dimensions of the rectangle and testing the other dimension. So for the right and left sides, match the point's X value to the upper-left or lower-right X value and test the Y value between both the upper and lower Y values.

By the way, this would be a little nicer to read if you use the @ operator, as is conventional for points:

```
on(X@Y, rectangle(ULX@Y, LRX@LRY)) :-
```

You could even get fancy and define your own `on` operator using `op/3`:

```
X@Y on rectangle(ULX@Y, LRX@LRY) :-
```

Prolog can be very pretty like that.

Comment: Hi @DanielLyons Thank you very much. Could you help me out in figuring out if a point is on a square given that a square only has the upperleft point and length. Such as on(point2d(X,Y), square(point2d(ULX, ULY), L)). Thank you